# How to change validate event in vee-validate?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vee-validate, vue-script-setup

I have working form validation, made with vee-validate and composition API script setup, build with Vite. By default, every input change or form submit is triggering validation. I want to change it to validate the field when it loses focus. It's called blur event. I found something in vee-validate documentation, for example to add a specific data attribute, but it's not working.
Here is my validation logic:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import BaseInput from "./components/BaseInput.vue";
import BaseSelect from "./components/BaseSelect.vue";
import { useField, useForm, configure } from "vee-validate";

const cars = [
...
];
let isDisabled = ref(false);
const required = (value) => {
  const requiredMessage = "This field is required!";
  if (value === undefined || value === null) return requiredMessage;
  if (!String(value).trim().length) return requiredMessage;

  return true;
};

const minLength = (number, value) => {
  if (String(value).trim().length < number)
    return "Please type minimum " + number + " characters";
  return true;
};
const maxLength = (number, value) => {
  if (String(value).trim().length > number)
    return "Please type maximum " + number + " characters";
  return true;
};

const validationSchema = {
  name: (value) => {
    const req = required(value);
    if (req !== true) return req;

    const min = minLength(3, value);
    if (min !== true) return min;

    const max = maxLength(16, value);
    if (max !== true) return max;

    return true;
  },

  car: (value) => {
    const req = required(value);
    if (req !== true) return req;

    return true;
  },
};

const { handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  validationSchema,
});
const { value: name } = useField("name");
const { value: car } = useField("car");

const submit = handleSubmit((values) => {
  alert("Submitted!");
});
</script>

<template>
  <form @submit="submit">
    <BaseInput
      v-model="name"
      label="Name*"
      type="text"
      :error="errors.name"
      :disabled="isDisabled"
    ></BaseInput>
    <BaseSelect
      v-model="car"
      label="Car brand*"
      :cars="cars"
      :error="errors.car"
      :disabled="isDisabled"
    ></BaseSelect>

    <button :disabled="!car || !name" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <p class="info">* required fields</p>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Dont call the validation, only call it with @blur="handleBlur"